# How I can put multiple colors in one element

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Multiple colors in one element

How can I effectively add multiple colors to a single element? I attempted to achieve this by utilizing the color mix function, but unfortunately, it did not yield the desired outcome. I'm now seeking guidance and innovative solutions to seamlessly blend various colors within a single element to create visually captivating web interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Gradients** to achieve something like that.

This sample code snippet shows how to create a `linear gradient` (from left to right) with the color of the rainbow to a div element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#gradent-div {
width:  100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="gradent-div">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to add **linear gradient** to a **text**, you can apply webkit properties, `-webkit-text-fill-color` will make the whole gradient-background transparent and `-webkit-background-clip` will fill the text with the gradient background

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content=
        "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Gradient Text</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: black;
        }
  
        h1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            font-size: 30px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
        }
    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <h1>This is for Text</h1>
</body>
  
</html>
```

PS - (Choose your background color wisely)

Comment: thanks for your help I am thankful for it, but I want something like that for text, for example, but I want the color, not the background.

Comment: @MostafaAhmed Ok, I made an edit to the answer and added what you need. (BTW you hadn't mention that in your question)

Answer (score -1):

For me It's not fully clear what you want from your question. But I hope this will help you out

```css
.gradient-section {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow);
}
```

```html
<section class="gradient-section">
  <h1>Is this what you are looking for?</h1>
  <p>This section has a gradient background.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for your help I am thankful for it, but I want something like that for text, for example, but I want the color, not the background.